# Is it possible to do a linear regression without the individual samples

Tags: regression

Just curious if I have only categorical predictors and a continuous response variable, is it possible to do a regression using only summary statistics of each possible combination of my indicators (e.g, sum, sum of squares, n, etc)?

Comment: What exactly do you have? You'll need some kind of data about the relation of the response to the predictors....

Comment: Yes, it's possible with what you have.  How you do it depends on the model you want, so let me just point out that you have a "full" model: your estimates of mean response (which can be obtained by dividing the sum by $n$ for each combination) give the most detailed regression possible of the response on the categories. This kind of modeling is usually done with formulas from Analysis of Variance.

Answer (score 6):

As whuber points out, I may well have misinterpreted the question; consequently I'll edit to answer it two ways. [I'm still making some assumptions here relating to the form of the model, so there's still some potential room for misinterpretation even now.]

1. If "in each category" means "at each combination of factor levels" (cells in a k-way table, for k categorical predictors), then you actually only need the counts and the sum of the y's at each combination (in each cell) to get the coefficients. (Sums of squares of y's would be needed for some other things, as suggested below.)
2. If by "in each category" you mean "for each categorical variable" then that would consist just of marginal summaries, and 
   marginal summaries (sums and sums of squares) are not sufficient.

   Here you need sums of cross products as well; $x_i'x_j$ (across all pairs of predictors) and $x_i'y$. (This is equivalent to finding the counts and sum of y's in each cell in 1. above)

   With those as well as sums and sums of squares (which are just $x_0'x_j$ and $x_0'y$ for $x_0=\mathbf{1}$, in order to fit a constant term), you can form $X'X$ (a matrix whose $i,j$ element is $x_i'x_j$) and $X'y$ (a column vector with $i$-th element $x_i'y$, in both cases indexing from $0$ rather than $1$) and hence attempt to solve the regression problem (i.e. solve the system $X'X \hat{\beta}=X'y$).

   This could then be done, for example, by forming the Cholesky decomposition of $X'X$ (don't attempt to directly invert $X'X$):

   If $A=X'X$ and $z = X'y$ you're trying to solve $A\hat{\beta}=z$ for symmetric (and hopefully positive definite) $A$.

   - Form $A=LL'$ (other versions of Cholesky form $LDL'$ or $R'R$ or $R'DR$, but the basic approach is similar)
   - Solve $L \zeta=z$ for $\zeta$ by forward substitution
   - Solve $L'\hat{\beta}=\zeta$ for $\hat{\beta}$ by back substitution

   You then have the parameter estimates

   If you need things like $R^2$ or $s^2$ you'll also need $y'y$.

Comment: Did you notice that the question concerns *categorical* explanatory variables? All these extra statistics you are requiring are unnecessary--and can be computed from the sums, counts, and sums of squares in each category, depending on how the categories are coded.

Comment: It's possible I've been interpreting the phrasing of the question incorrectly (my answer does point to the fact that I found the phrasing ambiguous, giving what would be needed if it was taken one way). Let's assume for simplicity that the x's in my exposition are all 0-1 variables; then if by "in each category" the intent was "at every combination of factor levels" (which wasn't how I interpreted it --  I took it as 'for each categorical variable'), then yes, what I say to compute would have already been computed, since they'd just be the counts in each combination of factor levels ...(ctd)

Comment: (ctd) ...  but under that interpretation the sums and sums of squares of the x's in each combination of factor levels would be redundant -- they'd all just be the count (which is part of why I didn't interpret it that way) - you only need the count and the sum of y in each combination of levels (to get the estimates). I'll come back to clarify my answer to cover that interpretation, because on reflection I think you're right that it's the actual intent.

Comment: @whuber hopefully this addresses the question better; rather than noting the ambiguity and sticking with my original interpretation, I now cover both interpretations.

Comment: I may come back and add more details and a specific example